# how to filter certain params when calling logger.warn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In a few places in my app I am logging the params hash:

```
logger.warn "Params: #{params.to_json.to_s}"
```

In the file `filter_parameter_logging.rb` I have added the following:

```
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [:password]
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += ["user.password"]
```

But passwords and passwords within the user hash are still being logged.  I was hoping that would work but I guess it is only for standard Rails logging.

Is there a similar catch-all way to filter out certain params when manually logging using `logger.warn`? or is the only approach to reject those params everywhere I'm logging them?

Comment: Is it really so onerous to `logger.warn "Params: #{params.except(:password).to_json}"`? In how many places are you explicitly logging the user password by mistake?!

Comment: However, rails does also have a built-in `filtered_parameters` method which applies the above filters.

Comment: What Rails version are you using?